# error in casting (input string was not in a correct format)

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm getting an error in my .net core api 'System.Number.StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan`1 str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)\r\n at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)\r\n at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt3' while using the reader function of sql data reader. below is the attached code.How to resolve this?

```
reader.NextResult();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader[0] != DBNull.Value && reader[1] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    groups.Add(new Group()
                    {
                        GroupId = reader[0] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                        SiteId = reader[1] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]),
                        GroupName = Convert.ToString(reader[2])
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: What values you are getting in `reader[0]` and `reader[1]` ?

Comment: You can't *cast* strings to integers. You need to *parse* those strings. `Convert.ToInt32` will parse the strings using the current' locale's settings for the decimal and thousand separators. Use `int.Parse` instead, and pass the desired locale as a `CultureInfo` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Int.TryParse` to handle if the string is not convertable.
some thing like this:

```
reader.NextResult();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader[0] != DBNull.Value && reader[1] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                groups.Add(new Group()
                {
                    GroupId = int.TryParse(reader[0].ToString(),out var groupId) ? groupId : 0,
                    SiteId = int.TryParse(reader[1].ToString(),out var siteId) ? siteId: 0,
                    GroupName = Convert.ToString(reader[2])
                });
            }
        }
```